# What’s the worst injury ever inflicted to Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

From all the canons that I have read or seen, I have seen Wolverine facing two worst injuries:

1. Being split into two by The Hulk.
2. Skin burning down by nuclear explosion (in *The Wolverine* movie)

Is there any other injury worse than this that has been inflicted on Wolverine?

Conditions:

a) Wolverine must be in his normal form. No power-suppressing materials must have been used on him (like they were later in *The Wolverine*).

b) Wolverine's death not included.

c) No mental or emotional injury included.

Comment: In Age of Apocalypse, Wolverine: 1) Permanently lost a hand to Cyclops 2) went down in a blimp that completely burnt up all of his skin (although he didn't have to worry about radiation damage). So, which continuities are acceptable?

Comment: Define “worst”? Without that, this is pretty much just an invitation to discussion, and therefore off-topic.

Comment: Does the Punisher literally steamrolling him qualify?

Comment: This might be an answer if fleshed out with a specific reference which I do not have at hand, but I recall an issue of Xmen, I think, in which Wolverine was combating another mutant/alien in which W was being destroyed and a single drop of his blood landed on a strange crystal/device and he regenerated.

Comment: Stepping on Lego pieces is the worst injury in the world, **in *my* opinion**!

Answer (score 7):

#### If you are excluding Wolverine's death, then the worst agony I can imagine him suffering was the extraction of his adamantium by Magneto in X-men #25 in 1993.

- **[Adamantium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium)** is supposedly unable to be altered by any force once it has been set. I imagine the magnetic field created by Magneto necessary to alter an immutable metal, not to mention the energy required should have been excruciating and easily one of the most terrible things to happen to Logan, that DIDN'T kill him.

[image]

*From X-Men #25; Marvel, 1993: part of the Fatal Attractions epic.
Script by Fabian Nicieza, pencils by Andy Kubert, inks by Matthew Ryan.*

Answer (score 1):

In an alternate universe Wolverine was killed by The Punisher.

He was thrown against a high voltage fence, which vaporized every cell of his body. That seems to have done the trick

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but his condition was "excluding Wolverine's death".

Comment: I thought that was referring to "the" death.  I will leave this up and let OF tell us what he meant by that

Comment: I guess the people who put the question on hold have a point, answers will be primarily opinion based; this case for example, for me the question could exclude all known deaths (even in an alternative universe), but for you it only excludes the main death. So at the moment we only have our own opinions :/